# WIll Web Apps be backported to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, webapps

I was wondering if the web app technology would be back ported to 12.04? I didn't know if this is where I would ask this question but I thought I would ask anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure whether it will be officially back-ported in a point release but the preview PPA has support for 12.04 already.  On your system, just run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview` then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview`

Source: https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview

Comment: When I tried this with 12.04 64bit I hit a bucket load of errors. Which, I felt, was a shame.